# Nested Quantifiers and Equivalences

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm a little confused with nested quantifiers when it comes to comparing two statements. I have this for example:

Assume: $$ P(x,y,z) : x + y = z $$

$$\forall x \forall y \exists z : P(x,y,z)$$

The domain is real numbers for all variables. Now I know the above statement evaluates to true since adding any two real numbers, you'll always have a value $z$  for which it is true.
Now the confusion arises with the following:

$$\exists z \forall x \forall y : P(x,y,z)$$

The way I read this: "There is a real number $z$ for every real number $x$ and for every real  number $y$". This statement is False but don't see why... wouldn't there be a value for $z$ for which this is true? I'm stuck on how to interpret these. They sound so similar yet I cannot see the difference.

Comment: The second way around, $z$ is independent of $x,y$. Could you find such a $z$ if the devil is then free to choose $x,y$ as he sees fit?

Comment: Your reading "There is a real number $z$ for every $\dots$" builds in a spurious possibility for $z$ to depend on $x$ and $y$. It is much better to read the existential quantifier $\exists z$ as "there exists $z$ such that" or as  "for at least one $z$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it as a game between players named $\exists$ and $\forall$. You’re $\exists$, and your goal is to make the statement $x+y=z$ true; your opponent is $\forall$, and his goal is to make it false. You pick your real numbers in the order in which the quantifiers appear.

With the first statement you always win: no matter what real numbers $x$ and $y$ he picks, you can pick the number $x+y$ for your $z$, and $P(x,y,z)$ will be true.

Now look at $\exists z\forall x\forall y(x+y=z)$: in this version of the game you have to play first. You pick some real number $z$. Can your opponent $\forall$ choose $x$ and $y$ to make you lose? Absolutely, and in lots of ways. For instance, he can choose $x=z$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Ok, so from I what I understood, you choose your number $z$ based on which quantifier comes first in the hierarchy? I pick $z=5$ for example, well 5 is the sum of 2 and 3. But wouldn't those go in the place of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Dmitri, suppose $z = 5$. For $\forall x\forall P(x, y, z)$ to be true, it must hold fo rall x, and for all $y$, not just $2$ and $3$. Every pair of numbers must sum to some given $z$. That's not the same as $\forall x\forall y \exists z$, where we can pick a different $z$ values, by letting $z_1 = x_1 + y_1$, and $z_2 = x_2 + y_2$, etc.

Comment: You're right. I forgot they're being looped through all real numbers. So in essence, $x$ and $y$ can choose whatever they want and $z$ can counter it with something else, correct? Is that a good way of seeing it as well?

Comment: Exactly! That's a good way to see it.

Comment: Great! I guess it's a matter of applying this principle with others! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dimitri: You’re welcome. The most important thing to bear in mind here is that the order matters. If you get to pick **after** your opponent, you can take his choices into account when you make yours; if you have to pick first, you can’t — and in this problem that turns out to be crucial.

Answer (score 5):

The second statement $$\exists z \forall x \forall y \;P(x, y, z)$$ is false because there is **no ONE** $z \in \mathbb R$ for which $P(x, y, z)$ is true for every possible pair of reals $(x, y)$.

I.e., there is no ONE $z \in \mathbb R$ such that $P(x, y, z)$ is true *no matter what the values of $x$ and $y$.*

Is there any $z$ for which $1 + 2 = z$ and $2 + 3 = z$? If there were such a $z$, we'd have $1+2 = 2 + 3$, which is absurd.

Comment: Remember, $x, y$ can be any values whatsoever!

Answer (score 0):

$\exists z \forall x \forall y : P(x,y,z)$ is the same thing as saying:

$\text{There exists a $z$ such that for all numbers $x$ and $y$, $x+y=z$ is true.}$

or equivalently,

$\text{There exists a $z$ such that the sum of any two numbers ($\in \mathbb{R}$) is equal to $z$.}$

Answer (score 0):

Does there exist a real number which equals the sum of *any* two numbers?

The intended meaning of the second statement in words can get read "there exists a real number z such that for any real number x, for any real number y, [(x+y)=z]."  In other words, **all** pairs of real numbers would have to sum to this real number z if it existed.